# Libmms and iOS 5, Xcode 4.2

Tags: objective-c, ios5, libmms

Every time I try complier my that is using the libmms. I recieved  follow linker error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_Status_GetNewStatusByKey", referenced from:
>         _report_progress in mms.o   "_Status_SetNewStatusByKey", referenced from:
>         _report_progress in mms.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)

Any help would be helpfully

Comment: Try completly removing libmms from your project, then adding it back in and clean/compile.

Comment: I have tries that and still receiving linker error

Comment: Do you have armv6 in your architecture build settings?

Comment: yes I do have armv6 in my architecture build setting